# Migrating from ADT to Xamarin, Xamarin cannot locate my copied Android sdk

Tags: android, build, sdk, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to migrate from ADT to Xamrin.

I have installed Xamarin on Windows.

I have installed sdk. But when I try to download tools and sdks from SDK manager I get and error like this:

[image]

But since I already had downloaded everything when I was using ADT, I copied the sdk folder to the new computer I have Xamarin on.

But Xamarin does not seem to be able to locate sdk. 
I have installed Android sdk here:

[image]

When I go to tools->options and I enter the address of the sdk folder, the red cross does not go away. I tried entering all subfolders in sdk folder.

[image]

What am I supposed to do? 
I've been dealing with this the whole day. No usefull link or guide since Xamarin is not stoll widely used. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a good idea to remove all spaces from pathes.

I use C:\Android as my base path, **c:\Android\SDK**, **c:\Android\NDK** etc. I had some serious problems with Xamarin and spaces / accented characters in path in previous versions.

Furthermore there's an Access Denied on your path in the first screenshot, add read/write rights recursively for the folder **c:\program files (x86)\Android** (Everyone - Full control if anything fails)